# instagram error code: 400 error

Tags: api, instagram

When a user authorizes their account this message is popping up?

```
 {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Client Disabled"}
```

How do I rectify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your application has been disabled, which is why you're seeing this - your best bet would be to check in with Instagram developer support.

Comment: Not specifically, but it's possible you've violated their terms of use or something (check the bottom of the page at http://instagram.com/developer/) - you'll need to get in touch with them to learn specifics.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't violated their terms from what I can tell. I searched the boards but there's nothing on "Client Disabled" error msg.

Comment: thank you. I contacted instagram and they told me what the problem was. I made adjustments so my code didn't slam their servers and they turned my ID back on.

Comment: @Andrew: what email address did you use to contact Instagram?

Answer (score 6):

I contacted apidevelopers @ instagram.com and the technical founder Mike responded and helped me through the issue.  My API client was making hundreds of request per second for the same user's media, and not responding to the message back from the server stating that the token had been rate limit.

Comment: can you please help me and give contact email for the developer API. we are facing the issue and need to contact them.